# Refinement panel show 3 items instead of 6

Tags: enterprise-search, refinement-panel

We are using SP 2013 enterprise edition. We have got a problem I think with the refinement panel.

When we refine the search results using a refiner in the refinement panel, it shows 3 items instead of 6. If I use the same refiner in the `query search box`, e.g.: `myEvent:"ABC Events"`, it shows all 6 of them, but when I refine via `refinement panel` I get only 3 items and it is the same `managed property` "myEvent" that is being used.

I have tested it with a different search page and the result is the same. 
FYI, this is all out of the box functionality. Nothing custom. I have done an index reset.

Any idea what could be the reason and how the query is constructed for refinement panels?

Answer (score 0):

1.Check the scoping of the search query and the refinement. There can be different search scope like **Intranet - 6 items** and **Web - 3 items**.

2.Next thing is to check Search Service Application in Central Administration, check Search Schema and Managed property myEvent if is **Refinable - Yes-Active**

That's all for now, if it doesn't help, we will try to figure out.

Comment: Could you please explain better your first point? How can I check that as scopes I believe were removed in SP2013. Thank you.

Comment: Are the files from the same web or from different webs?

Comment: they are from the same web application. and the managed property is refinable and Yes-Active

Comment: But i mean same web, are they from same web or from different webs?

Comment: They are from the same subsite e.g.: /sites/pubs/publications/ and actually from the same library, but from two different folders.

Comment: have you resolved this issue?